# Where are the PostgreSQL logs on macOS?

Tags: postgresql, logging, macos

I would like to take a look at the PostgreSQL log files to see what my app writes to them but I can't find them.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

On OS X, if you're using the EnterpriseDB installation of PostgreSQL, your log files will be in `/Library/PostgreSQL/8.4/data/pg_log`

Of course, you'll want to substitute 8.4 for whichever version number you're running.

Answer (score 244):

On OSX Homebrew installation the log can be found at:

Latest Homebrew:

```
/opt/homebrew/var/log/postgres.log
```

or older:

```
/usr/local/var/log/postgres.log
```

or for older version of postgres (< 9.6)

```
/usr/local/var/postgres/server.log
```

Bonus - check if PostgreSQL is running using Homebrew:

```sh
brew services info --all
```

Comment: I had to uncomment some logging related lines in `/usr/local/var/postgres/postgresql.conf`

Comment: if you have a specific version installed via homebrew, the path might be different, e.g. `/opt/homebrew/var/log/postgresql@14.log`

Answer (score 76):

Just ask your database:

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    pg_settings 
WHERE 
    category IN( 'Reporting and Logging / Where to Log' , 'File Locations')
ORDER BY 
    category,
    name;
```

In my case, it's in "/Library/PostgreSQL/8.4/data/pg_log"

Comment: hmm, in my case it's stderr :/

sql result as csv here: http://pastebin.com/20C92z2v

Comment: u I like the "cross platform" solution

Comment: This doesn't work if your database failed to start and you don't know where the log files are yet.

Answer (score 55):

The `plist` used to launch your Postgres on boot may also set the logfile:

```
$ dir ~/Library/LaunchAgents
org.postgresql.postgres.plist

$ cat ~/Library/LaunchAgents/org.postgresql.postgres.plist
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  [...]
  <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
  <string>/usr/local/var/postgres/server.log</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

So in this case, `/usr/local/var/postgres/server.log`.

Answer (score 17):

For Apple M1(Big Sur / Monterey) users who installed postgres using homebrew the location is -

```
/opt/homebrew/var/log/postgres.log
```

Answer (score 9):

If you are using [Postgres.app](http://postgresapp.com/), you can find the Data Directory location in the Preferences dialog box. In that directory, the log is at `postgres-server.log`.

For example, on my machine, the log is at `/Users/nofinator/Library/Application Support/Postgres/var-9.4/postgres-server.log`.

Answer (score 2):

I have different Postgresql versions installed on my mac (with macports), and all the logs can be found here

```
/opt/local/var/log/postgresql84/postgres.log
/opt/local/var/log/postgresql91/postgres.log
/opt/local/var/log/postgresql92/postgres.log
```

Answer (score 0):

Postgresapp 9.3.5.1 and later keep a server log. The log is inside the data directory, named postgres-server.log.

Answer (score 0):

And for users of **macports**, expect something like `/opt/local/var/log/postgresql11` (assuming you are running postgresql 11) after upgrading to Big Sur.

Answer (score 0):

**Postgres 13**

All logs are arranged per in the order of dates in postgres version 13.
The correct folder to find it is :

```
sudo ls /Library/PostgreSQL/13/data/log
```

Here you can see all the logs file that were created to select any one log file use

`sudo vim /Library/PostgreSQL/13/data/log/postgresql-2021-08-20_051906.log`

Comment: this also works for postgres 12