# Django virtual environment, where are the logs of Postgres saved in mac?

Tags: django, postgresql

I have a Django project running in virtual environment(in MAC OS), where can I access the postgres logs?
Before asking this question,I have looked into following posts but I could not find logs in the places they suggest
* http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/runtime-config-logging.html 
* [How to check status of PostgreSQL server Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7975414/check-status-of-postgresql-server-mac-os-x)
* http://www.postgresqlformac.com/server/error_startup_fails_after_i.html
* [Where are the PostgreSQL logs on Mac OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2563494/where-postgresql-logs-are-on-mac-os-x)

Comment: You should search first before submit a question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2563494/where-postgresql-logs-are-on-mac-os-x

Comment: I looked in those posts but I cannot find it there!

Comment: I think you might try install it via Homebrew http://brew.sh/. It's easy.

Comment: I have installed it long back and have lots of data in it, dont want to reinstall now.

Comment: Backup the data is not hard. Sometimes we should choose the easy way!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You may `find` it using the following command:

   ```
   sudo find / -name pg_log
   ```

   Output:

   ```
   /Library/PostgreSQL/9.2/data/pg_log
   ```
2. If the above attempt fails, try to find log location in your plist

   My plist is located at `/Library/LaunchDaemons/`, another possible location is `/Library/LaunchAgents/`.

   Check if `com.edb.launchd.postgresql-9.2.plist` contains the following section:

   ```
   <dict>
     ......
     <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
     <string>/usr/local/var/postgres/server.log</string>
   </dict>
   ```

   In the above case, the log is located at `/usr/local/var/postgres/server.log`

Comment: Nothing is showing up with that command. Is pg_log the log file for psql? Where can I set the log file path details for psql?

Comment: It worked, I have my logs in /usr/local/var/postgres/server.log