# Forgot Password for PostgreSQL 13 db on Mac

Tags: postgresql, psql, pgadmin-4

I am new to PostgreSQL and before I start learning got stuck in the password;
I have forgotten my password to PostgresSQL 13 path when I use pdAdmin tool.

I use mac. Apologies for basic questions.

I went through multiple articles, videos but I am unable to through different steps.

Steps I did:

- Downloaded PostgreSQL 13, logged into pgAdmin, forgot password to PostgreSQL 13 db
- Found the "pg_hba.conf" and edited the method from "md5" to "trust"

Steps I am unable to proceed and stuck:

- Restart the postgresql service (where and how do I do this? via launching Terminal?)
- Start psql session as postgres (how to launch? I searched the psql via search. When I entered "psql -U postgres", its asking for "Database" and "Port (5432)" and "Username". I am unaware to find these"

This is where I am unable to go to next step to use ALTER USER command to reset.

I went through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12720967/how-to-change-postgresql-user-password) but when I enter the command "sudo -u user_name psql db_name", its asking for all information above which I don't have knowledge yet. Same as above points where I am getting stuck.

[image: postgreSQL 13]

[image: psql]

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: You have a connection problem, not a password problem. Is postgresql running? Have you inspected the logs?

Comment: No how do I check that please?

Comment: See [Where are the PostgreSQL logs on macOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2563494/10318835).

Comment: Thanks Steeve. I could now locate the file on data/postgresql.conf | How do I now proceed? What's the next steps pls?

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Mac, then [Postgresapp](https://postgresapp.com/) from [Postgres official documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/download/macosx/) gives you a straightforward way to change the password. Install the app and click Server Setting on the app and Change Password.
[image]

Answer (score -1):

If you installed Postgres using brew (That's most common case)..

To access postgres

```
# psql postgres
```

`postgres` is the database name, and after this you will be logged into psql and will see postgres db. You can switch to your database as -

```
\c <your-db-name-here>
```

To start/stop/restart

```
brew services start postgresql
brew services stop postgresql
brew services restart postgresql
```

If you did not install using brew and want to do so -

```
brew install postgres
```