# pgAgent Jobs not running

Tags: postgresql, pgagent

I have created a job with steps, but when I click on "Run Now" in pgAdmin, nothing happens.  There are no statistics on the job.  Has anyone encountered and resolved this?  Below is a screenshot of what I'm seeing:

[image: PgAdminScreenshot]

Here is a screenshot of the enabled jobs:

[image]

Here are my windows services showing that both PostGres and pgAgent are running:

[image]

Comment: Is the daemon or service running? And did you enable all steps? An empty screenshot doesn't show anything, nobody can help you with that. It's about the things that you did, how you did it and how you validated your work.

Comment: The Postgres Service is definitely running.  This is installed on a Windows machine so there is no daemon as far as I know.  What do you mean by an empty screenshot?  I uploaded a screenshot of pgAdmin, highlighted that the agent was there, and showed the job.  I've added another with the enabled jobs shown.

Comment: PostgreSQL could be running, but if pgAgent is not running no job will be executed. That's a second service you have to start, check the logfiles.

Comment: pgAgent is running.  I've even restarted it:

Comment: Do you know where the log file is located for pgAgent on Windows?

Comment: Just ask your database, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2563565/724039

Comment: @Luuk sorry for the delay:  I have gone to the DB and run the query you suggested.  I have checked data/log, but don't see anything related to the agent.  There's nothing in the results specifying the PG Agent Log.